# What is the expected value of x/(x+y) if x and y are independent log normal random variables?

Tags: random-variables, expected-value, density-function

Suppose that $X$ and $Y$ are independent log normal random variables. Is it possible to compute a closed form solution (or approximate closed form) to the expected value of $X/(X+Y)$?

I know that the sum of log normal random variables does not have a simple distribution as discussed [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/238529/the-sum-of-independent-lognormal-random-variables-appears-lognormal). How about the expected value of $X_1/(X_1+...X_n)$ where $X_i$ are independent log normal random variables?

Comment: If $X_i$'s are i.i.d. then the answer is $\frac 1 n$.

Comment: let $F$ be the joint distribution function of $X$ and $Y$, then if $F(X,Y)=F(Y,X)$. Then $E[\frac{X}{X+Y}]=\frac{1}{2}$

Comment: @VishaalSudarsan Is this result true only for log normal distributions or for any distribution? Could you please elaborate on that or provide a reference?